# Interpreting Coefficients of a Dummy variables derived from an Ordinal variable

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, binary-data, predictor

I have a variable that is measure societal complexity (SC) on a 3 point scale. 1 being the least complex and 3 being the most complex, and I think that this can safely be classed as a ordinal variable.

However, the software for the model I am using this variable in currently does not allow ordinal variables, so I decided to convert this into 2 binary variables for SC1 and SC3, using SC2 as the baseline.

My question is how should I intepret these coefficients? My intention when doing this was to be able to say SC1 is so much worse than SC2 and that SC3 is so much better than SC2.

However, upon further contemplation, are these coefficients saying something closer to SC1 is so much worse than *not* SC1 (ie. SC2 & SC3) and that SC3 is so much better than *not* SC3 (ie. SC1 & SC2)?

If so, is there a way to test something closer to my intention?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I am using an adaptation of a method developed by Freckleton & Jetz (2009) which controls for and estimates the influences of Phylogenetic and Spatial interdependencies in a linear model. The method is developed in R - although is not available in any CRAN package. Although I think my question applies to the general use of binary variables in a linear model.

I have found little information discussing the matter. Although a number of texts have suggested converting likert scale scores into a number of binary variables (which can also arguabley be described as ordinal varibles), they do not discuss the issue of in-group vs out-group when using a number of dummy variables representing a ordinal variable.

**EDIT**

Having considered recoding the data so that SC1 was the baseline, and then using an ordered approach that was suggested by Mark Step below and could be tabled as such:

```
   2.  3. 
1. 0   0
2. 1   1
3. 0   1
```

This would be equivalent to

```
   1.  2.
1. 1   0
2. 0   1
3. 0   0
```

Which is the same result we started with, so I am unsure if this suggestion is any different to my intial attempt.

Comment: Is your `SC` variable a response or predictor? If a predictor, it probably does not matter if it is ordinal or not.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a bit more detail in your question.

You can codify a factor with p-levels using indicator variables. The interpretation is unchanged. If you were to form a linear model then the parameter estimates are set based on the codes used for your indicator (binary) variables.

As a basic example, say you had constructed a model with a predictors `cMWeight`, `I1` and `I2` where `I1` and `I2` codified a 3-level factor (as in your case) and you get the following results:

```
Coefficients:
             Value Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 1.0312     0.0029 352.2184   0.0000
cMWeight    0.0503     0.0011  47.5039   0.0000
I1          0.0722     0.0042  17.3240   0.0000
I2         -0.0245     0.0041  -5.9097   0.0000
```

If you had coded SC0 as $I1=1$ and $I2=1$ then your model for that factor level would be formed by adopting those values in the regression equation, something along the lines of:

${\rm response} = 1.0312 + (0.0503 \times {\rm cMWeight}) + (0.0722 \times I_1) + ((-0.0245) \times I_2) + \epsilon$

Setting I1 and I2 to 1 gives your result for SC0. You can derive analogous results for each of your coded levels. In this example the interpretation results in just a different intercept term.

Comment: Sorry I had not included enough information. What information do you think is required - I will add this to the question for other readers. I had considered your suggestion, where SC1 would be the baseline, and a data point in SC3 would have a 1 for both SC2 & SC3, but was unsure if this was common practice or had any adverse effects. Do you know if this is the case?

Comment: Did you research the question before hand? What have you learned to date? What model you are assuming, what is the response, what software you are using and some minimal output. I learned about the approach at uni so I cannot say whether it is common practice. I do not think there is anything particularly unusual about the approach. I think that until recently it was the standard approach to include ordinal data using indicators.

Comment: I have ammended my question with respect to your suggestions. Although I have not included output, as I feel this question is broader than any specific analysis. I am more concerned with the practice of converting a ordinal variable into a number of binary variables and which of my interpretations described above are correct. Do of any materials I could read that you may have been given at university?